# Show that if $kc+lm = g$ then gcd$(k,l)=1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I'm looking at this problem, and it doesn't seem too complicated, but I feel like I'm missing something

---

Let gcd$(c,m) = g$

a)Show that if $kc+lm = g$ then gcd$(k,l)=1$
b)Show that if we write $m = m'g, c = c'g$, then gcd$(c',m') =1 $
c)Prove that $$ec \equiv fc  \text{ mod } m \Leftrightarrow e \equiv f \text{ mod }m'$$

---

So $k$ and $l$ need to be relatively prime, otherwise $kc + lm$ would equal some mulitple of $g$? Or am I missing something here?

Comment: You're absolutely correct! Try thinking about factoring c and m ( as g is a common factor) and factoring also k and l ( if we suppose they have a common factor).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if you can fill in the arguments from here.

To show that gcd$(k,l)=1$, you need some integers $a$ and $b$ such that $ak+bl=1$. Note that if gcd$(c,m)=g$, then $c/g$ and $m/g$ are integers, since $g$ divides both of them. Using $c$ and $m$, you can get your $a$ and $b$.

To show that gcd$(c',m')=1$, say that gcd$(c',m')=h$. If $h>1$, what must be true about $gcd(c,m)$?

For the last statement, recall that this is equivalent to $m|c(e-f) \iff m'|(e-f)$. Using the fact that $m'$ and $c'$ are relatively prime, and that $m=m'g, c=c'g$, how can you simplify these congruences?

Comment: This was very helpful, thanks!